# Inside a Camel Processor, variable declared to hold property from camel property place holder is not working

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have a property `PFlow_XXXX="some value"` defined which is read using camel property placeholder. Inside the processor, the property value is constructed by extracting the `xxx value` from file name.Now when I try to get the value of this property inside the processor like this

```
exchange.getContext().resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{xsdPathVar}}"));
```

where `String xsdPathVar = "PFlow_"+extracting from file`.

But this is not working. Can some one help me how to read the property value from a string variable.

Comment: What is not working, can you provide a better example or explain a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

When using `propertyPlaceholder` you can inject your properties in beans by using the `@PropertyInject`annotation:

```
@PropertyInject(value = "xsdPathVar")
String xsdPathVar;

Public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    ...
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're asking for?